# two different menu bar collapse in single menubar when it's responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have two different inline lists. when switches to responsive mode two menu bars are collapse in single button. Is it possible. please give any ideas or solution.

This is my code

```
     <header>
            <div class="header_menu_1">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">1233434</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1233434</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1233434</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1233434</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1233434</i></a></li>                   
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                 <div class="header_menu_2">
                     <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Homes</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **when switches to responsive mode** ???

Comment: resize my window in 320px

Comment: I have posted an answer. Did it work? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a3uwdked/)

js:

```
var $tempData = $(".header_menu_1 ul").html();
var $tempData2 = $(".header_menu_2 ul").html();
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(document).width() < 321){
        $(".header_menu_1 ul").html($tempData+$tempData2);
        $(".header_menu_2 ul").hide();
    }else{
        $(".header_menu_2 ul").html($tempData2);
         $(".header_menu_1 ul").html($tempData);
        $(".header_menu_2 ul").show();
    }
})
```